# How do I toggle a class within a loop between a table row and map points?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 10 rows in a table that contains the address of each tag on a map. I am trying to add a click event to each tag on the map to it's corresponding table row. Instead of writing each click event separately I'm attempting to do it through a for loop. What's the best way to do this? The for loop below works for only the last iteration but not for all.

```
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        var maptag = "#maptag";
        var maprow = "#maprow";
        $(maptag + +i).click(function() {
            console.log('in the hole!');
            $(maprow + +i).toggleClass('highlight');
            return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need a closure

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var maptag = "#maptag";
  var maprow = "#maprow";
  (function(x) {  // IIFE
    $(maptag + +x).click(function() {
      console.log('in the hole!');
      $(maprow + +x).toggleClass('highlight');
      return false;
    })
  }(i))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is scoping. What's happening is when you create your `click` event, `i` is the current value in the loop. However, when the `click` even is triggered, that `i` is set to the state it was at the end of the loop (i.e., your last one).

What you need to do is wrap it in a function to affect the scope. Something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    var maptag = "#maptag";
    var maprow = "#maprow";
    $(maptag + i).click((function (i) { return function() {
        console.log('in the hole!');
        $(maprow + i).toggleClass('highlight');
    })(i));
}
```

This looks a little weird, but what you're doing is wrapping the function that'll actually trigger in another function, which is self-calling:

```
(function (i) {
   // will trigger immediately
}(i);
```

You pass in your `i` there, but then the function inside which is returned uses an `i` which is actually a different variable. The inner `i` doesn't change when the loop changes, so it'll have the value you expect when the `click` is actually triggered.

---

P.S., never seen `variableName + +i` before. Not sure if that was a typo, or some special syntax I'm unaware of, but if it is, it'd seem unnecessary here. Your `return false` is also unnecessary, as without it, it'll implicitly return `null` which is also a falsey value (unless you're explicitly checking for `false` somewhere with an `===`).

Comment: The + +i converts the number to a string

Comment: @xgrioux Adding the `i` to `maprow` is what converts it to a string. I'm not sure exactly what JavaScript is doing with the extra plus (I would have expected a syntax error), but just trying something like `var a = + +2;` just gives me a number, so it seems completely extraneous.

Comment: Oh you're right! I took out the + and it still works